# How can I maintain a fixed image on my page, without be affected by the scroll page?

Tags: javascript, css, background, background-image

I want to get this effect
https://flowingbytes.com/REVEALER_DUDA/
How do you achieve a fixed background effect where the image stays in place while scrolling through the page?
How do you achieve a fixed background effect where the image stays in place while scrolling through the page? **I don't want to use the background-attachment: fixed property** because it's incompatible with iPhones and other browsers, and I want this effect to look good on any device.Any solution? Any advice?

This is the code:

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <div id="creativity" style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden; background-image: url('images/fondo.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed;">
            <!-- Enlace con Imagen del marco -->
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="frameLink" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 300px; height: 600px; cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="images/marco.png" alt="Marco" id="frameImage" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- END CREATIVITY CONTENT -->
```

I have done the effect as you can see on the link example, but I want to get it without fixed tag.
Here there is another good example of what I want to achieve:
https://demo.teads.com/?content=publishers%2Fteads-tech_english.html&vast=https%3A%2F%2Fs8t.teads.tv%2Fvast%2F6753877076571941&utm_source=showcase&view=mobile&unsupportedDevices=ctv,desktop

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it looks like the image is just a background image

Comment: Make a div.parent. set .parent position: relative; make div.bg, set .bg position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%, left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; z-index: -1;

Comment: This is a basic HTML code without JavaScript insertions or complex styles. As you can notice, I have only added "lorem ipsum" text to generate scroll and an image frame to partly emulate a mobile device
As you can see in the HTML I've included, which is where the effect I want to achieve is actually solved, it's enough to use background-attachment: fixed; to keep the background static while you scroll. What I want is to achieve exactly the same effect, but without using background-attachment: fixed, as it is incompatible with iOS devices, as you can see at https://caniuse.com/?search=fixed.

Comment: @Jawad ..thanks but I don't want to use fixed. This is the tag I want to avoid...because it doesn't work properly in some iOS devices...

Comment: @FLOWINGBYTES: if can't use background-attachment: fixed; than you can use position: fixed; instead with z-index. Also there is position: sticky;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674255/background-attachment-fixed-is-not-working-on-mobile-devices

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675265/question-about-a-mobile-friendly-alternative-to-using-background-attachment-fix

Comment: Please explain why the linked duplicates aren't working for you?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.parallax-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px; /* Set the height as needed */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax-background::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://static-cse.canva.com/blob/1156550/tools-feature_transparent-image_hero_mobile.2bae9e7e.jpg'); /* Replace YOUR_BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL with the actual URL of your background image */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff; /* Set the text color */
  text-align: center; /* Align the text as needed */
  /* Add any additional text styling as desired */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div id="creativity" class="parallax-background">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Your Title</h1>
      <p>Your paragraph text goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use parallax-background
its compatible with most of browsers

Comment: Author already mentioned that he doesn't want to use the background-attachment property as it doesn't work with some of the ios devices

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for.

Background image is an actual image tag as a direct decendant of the body.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 14px/1.618 "Segoe UI";
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
header, main, footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fafafa;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
}
.parallax-bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4gBc.png" class="parallax-bg" />
  <header><h1>This is the header</h1></header>
  <main>
    <h2>This is main content</h2>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
  </main>
  <footer><h2>This is footer content</h2></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the CSS property
`background-attachment: fixed` to create a fixed image that remains unaffected when scrolling. But the same effect can be achieved with JS.

The `div` element with class `parallax` has a background image with `background-size: 200%;` so the scroll effect imitates the CSS effect properly.

To achieve the same effect with JS we need to manipulate the background position on Y axis while scrolling.

So basically to mimic the CSS `background-attachment: fixed` with JS we need the background image of `div.parallax` to have the `background-position-y: 100%;` initially and decrease it to 0% while scrolled down to the bottom of the page.

**Code Breakdown:**

```
const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

`documentHeight` is the height of entire document and `windowHeight` is the viewport height.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
            const parallaxAmount = (((documentHeight - windowHeight) - scrollPosition) / (documentHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;
            parallaxElement.style.backgroundPositionY = `${parallaxAmount}%`;
});
```

**Calculation for the effect**

`const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;` gets the current vertical scroll position of the window.

`documentHeight - windowHeight` This subtracts the viewport height from the total document height. This represents the scrollable area of the page.

`(documentHeight - windowHeight) - scrollPosition`This represents the remaining scrollable portion of the page (the distance from the top of the visible content to the document bottom).

`/ (documentHeight - windowHeight)`This divides the result above by the total scrollable area which helps us to get a percentage by multiplying the result with 100.

```
parallaxElement.style.backgroundPositionY = `${parallaxAmount}%`;
```

This manipulates background position on Y axis. Voila! our effect is achieved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fixed Background Image (No background-attachment)</title>
    <style>
        .parallax {
            position: relative;
            background-image: url(https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w1200/2023/10/free-images.jpg);
            background-color: #000;
            height: 300px;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 200%;
            background-position-y: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"></div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque commodi ea sunt? Perspiciatis rerum eligendi non ducimus veniam blanditiis eveniet, adipisci ratione fugiat et velit, maxime modi eum, incidunt magni.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        const parallaxElement = document.querySelector('.parallax');
        const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;


        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
            const parallaxAmount = (((documentHeight - windowHeight) - scrollPosition) / (documentHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;
            parallaxElement.style.backgroundPositionY = `${parallaxAmount}%`;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*It's written without `background-attachment: fixed` as mentioned in the question.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community thank you for the suggestion. I am certainly changing it.